# Flow - Fast Create not executing

Tags: flow

I have a flow that seems to be skipping over a Fast Create element. I've checked the collection being created several times and cannot find anything wrong with it.
I added screens to see what happens when I add the Fast Lookup and the Fast Create to the screen. They both start as null, and after the Lookup happens, it's value becomes "true". After the Create happens, it's value becomes "false". But I don't get an error message to help me understand why and nothing was created.

Anyone have ideas on what is happening here or even a way to debug this?

Comment: As far as I can tell this only happens with one of my leads, none of the others. Still can't figure out why, but it's not as bad with that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if your Fast Create is not doing anything, that the Collection is empty. Rather than giving you an error, the system just continues on as if nothing has happened. The way to test this is in the question. When the value of the Fast Create element is False that means it didn't run, usually because the collection was empty. Go back and look at your collection to test, perhaps using the method listed here on another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a screen to display the values of your records. I found a suggested solution of how to loop through the elements and add to a text template for the screen [here](http://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AwtcIAC). With a link to an image displaying the steps [here](http://goravseth.clarify-it.com/d/k2gkhe).
Update:
Suggested steps from link:

> **SalesforceYoda**
>
> The trick here is getting the other non-Id values out of the sObject
>   Collection, and to do that, you'll need a loop. Where it gets really
>   hairy is getting it laid out correctly. I haven't built this yet, it's
>   entirely theoretical, but here's what I would attempt.
>
> First, make a new variable (we'll call it varDisplayText) to hold all
>   of your text.
>
> Then, in your loop, pass the Collection to a standard sObject
>   Variable.
>
> From there, use an Assignment element to Add (not equals!) the first
>   value of the first column to varDisplayText.
>
> Then (and I think you can do this in the same Assignment element, I am
>   pretty sure it will do it in order), use varDisplayText again but
>   instead of using Equals, use Add, and add the text string ", ".
>
> Add another line in the same element (or a new Assignment element if
>   necessary), use varDisplayText again, with Add, then the first value
>   in your second column.
>
> Add another line in the same element (or a new Assignment element if
>   necessary), use varDisplayText again, with Add, then the comma text
>   string again, but with a line break character afterwards.
>
> Point back to your loop so you can get the next set of values in your
>   collection.
>
> When the flow runs, it should do the Assignment with the add, which
>   functions as concatenation, for each row, creating a different row of
>   text.
>
> I am REALLY not certain this would work, but it's what I would try; it
>   works on paper. Otherwise, I think you're limited to a VF page here.

Comment: Unfortunately those links seem to not work. I added text elements, but they only tell me that the element did not execute, I'm not sure how to figure out why.

Comment: @denvergreene yea i just tried them both myself and they are broken... I just fixed them.

Comment: I've added your test to the flow, and found out that I'm not even in the spot to use it yet. First thought, You can have an SObject Collection of a custom object, right?

It appears that the collection I am trying to Fast Create is empty. I look through some collections to find the appropriate data. I assign a new SObject loop variable all of the appropriate values, and then add that SObject to a new collection. I can confirm that all of the loop variable has all of the correct values, but it now seems it's not added to the new collection.

Comment: @denvergreene Yoda was actually the responder on that other link. Maybe update the above question with a screen shot of your flow, it might help pin point the problem.

Comment: Ah I get what happened now. 

So I actually think I have an answer to this problem. I think I'll edit the question to be more clear and post an answer for others. And I think I'll look around for my 'adding to collection' problem, because an answer for that is probably already out there. Thanks for your help!